# Slow thinking tasks in job interviews

Tags: interviewing

In his book "Thinking fast and slow", Daniel Kahneman describes a series of research tasks used for measuring slow thinking. One example is the "add one" task, where a participant is read four single digit numbers, and asked to repeat them back with one added. According to the author, this task put a high strain on your ability for analytical thinking (system 2, as he calls it), and your level of exhaustion can be measured from the dilation of your pupils.

It seems like the perfect task to put in a job interview where you would want to gauge the participants' ability for analytical thinking, without necessarily wanting to put them through a full technical interview. Maybe you don't need a candidate with some concrete expertise, but rather someone you would deem generally "intelligent".

What would be potential downsides or further benefits of such an approach?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If it's to weed out a number of possibly well qualified applicants using a test that has little to nothing to do with your job requirements, then this sounds like a winner.

Comment: Is the ability to repeat back a list of numbers after adding one to them a key skill for whatever role you're interviewing for?

Comment: If you asked me to do that in a job interview I would find it strange, no matter how you sold it to me and walk away.

Answer (score 6):

> It seems like the perfect task to put in a job interview

Unless you have experimented thoroughly with these sorts of tasks as predictors of good employees in your specific company, these "tasks" fall into the same category as other useless "brain teaser" questions.

Terrible idea, IMHO. And I would walk away from any company that thought this was a way to hire the best candidates.

see: https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2013/06/google-finally-admits-that-its-infamous-brainteasers-were-completely-useless-for-hiring/277053/

Note that Kahneman himself has never (and I posit, would never) propose using these "tasks" themselves during an interview.

see: https://www.inc.com/jessica-stillman/hiring-job-interviews-daniel-kahneman.html

Interviewing isn't easy. Unfortunately, there are no great shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Even if (and it's a really big "if") you had decent reasons to assume that such a test was a good predictor of ability in the job you're hiring for. Your ability to actually administer and interpret the results of such a test in a job interview scenario is going to be to all intents and purposes zero

> your level of exhaustion can be measured from the dilation of your pupils

This may well be true.. but you aren't going to be able to measure pupil dilation with any accuracy, nor can you effectively control for confounding factors such as changes in ambient light levels, anxiety or excitement in the person (pupils dilate in response to adrenaline), or any number of perfectly normal reasons for increased pupil dilation that have nothing to do with what you're looking for.

The underlying principle behind this might be more scientifically plausible for evaluating a candidate than asking them their star-sign - but in actual practice it's going to be about as useful.

All in all I have to say that this, like so many interview gimmicks that promise a shortcut around actually constructing and conducting a well put together interview that assesses a candidate X's suitability for role Y is a complete an utter waste of time. Both the candidates *and* the interviewers.